# How do you preseed debconf from a previously installed package?

Tags: preseed, debconf

I would like to install a package (CouchDB 2.1) without having to manually respond to the prompt. I believe that preseeding `debconf` is the way this is done.

The debconf manual () says this:

> The  easiest  way  to set up the database is to install the packages
>   on one machine and answer their questions as usual

So after installing the package on one node, I looked at `/var/cache/debconf/config.dat` and I see the following has been added:

```
Name: couchdb/adminpass_mismatch
Template: couchdb/adminpass_mismatch
Owners: couchdb

Name: couchdb/bindaddress
Template: couchdb/bindaddress
Value: 0.0.0.0
Owners: couchdb
Flags: seen

Name: couchdb/cookie
Template: couchdb/cookie
Value: monster
Owners: couchdb
Flags: seen

Name: couchdb/error_setting_password
Template: couchdb/error_setting_password
Owners: couchdb

Name: couchdb/have_1x_databases
Template: couchdb/have_1x_databases
Owners: couchdb

Name: couchdb/mode
Template: couchdb/mode
Value: clustered
Owners: couchdb
Flags: seen

Name: couchdb/nodename
Template: couchdb/nodename
Value: couchdb@domain.com
Owners: couchdb
Flags: seen
```

And similarly a couple of 'verses'? where added to the `passwords.dat` file

Should I just append this to `/var/cache/debconf/config.dat` on the other machines? Or, how can I use the info in this database to install without prompts on future machines?

Also, I see that the password fields have been similarly added to passwords.dat. can I just append those as well? (They are not sensitive since they can be changed very easily)

Comment: Actually the answer really is as simple as copying the lines to files on other servers. But I'll leave this up because it took me a while to figure this out and maybe it can help someone else

Comment: Of course it may help someone else. You can even answer to your own question and accept the answer, this would be even better.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that just appending the new lines to `config.dat` and `passwords.dat` works for future installs.

So:

1. Install a package normally
2. Figure out what was added to the `config.dat` and `passwords.dat` files (I diffed the before and after `.dat` files)
3. Append the lines created by your package installation to the `.dat` files on other server nodes